# Robolectric "Failed to create a android.widget.Button" error

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

When I try to run my robolectric tests I receive exception:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create a android.widget.Button`
However if activity doesn't contains any buttons everything runs ok, but I need buttons :)
I use robolectric `2.0-alpha-3-SNAPSHOT`, what is more few days ago all tests was run successfully. 
Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved this problem! My buttons used text color defined like: 
`<color name="TEXT">@android:color/white</color>` it seems that robolectric doesn't have support for `@android:color` values, so replacing it by `<color name="TEXT">#FFF</color>` solved my problem

Comment: Any idea why would this work, because its not in my case. I am setting a color `<color name="foo">#000000</color>` to my activity background. e.g. container.setBackgroundColor(R.color.foo);